# Auction Timer is not working as expected in Asp.net webAPI

Tags: c#, idisposable, concurrentdictionary, system.timers.timer

```
public class AuctionTimer : IDisposable
{
    public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuctionTimer> Timers;

    private readonly Timer timer;

    static AuctionTimer()
    {
        Timers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuctionTimer>();
    }

    private AuctionTimer(string AuctionID, int ExecutionTime)
    {
        this._AuctionID = AuctionID;
        timer = new Timer();
        TimeCount = ExecutionTime;
        timer.Interval = new TimerUtil().getAuctionInterval();
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => MonitorElapsedTime();
        timer.Start();
    }

    private int TimeCount { get; set; }

    private string _AuctionID { get; set; }

    public static void StartTimer(string AuctionID, int ExecutionTime)
    {
        var newTimer = new AuctionTimer(AuctionID, ExecutionTime);
        if (!Timers.TryAdd(AuctionID, newTimer))
        {
            newTimer.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void StopTimer(string AuctionID)
    {
        AuctionTimer oldTimer;
        if (Timers.TryRemove(AuctionID, out oldTimer))
        {
            oldTimer.Dispose();
        }
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Stop might not be necessary since we call Dispose
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
    }

    private void MonitorElapsedTime()
    {
        if (TimeCount == new TimerUtil().getAuctionInterval())
        {
            StopTimer(_AuctionID);
            //do the other process in db 
        }
        else
        {
            TimeCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Following  is the code for my Auction Timer what i am trying to do here is making an auction storing starting and ending date so lets say an auction is going to last for 5 hours so the end date will be 5 hours from current time i am starting the Auction timer right after storing the end date for the auction it is working as expected but the problem i am facing now is the timer is bit delay from the end time around 2,3 minutes roughly that's  means the process which is suppose to run immediately after the auction expires is running 2,3 minutes  late i am not really sure what i am missing here.

Comment: Is this running inside your WebAPI project? That's unlikely to work without some kind of scheduling engine.

Comment: @DavidG yes running inside the WebAPI project

Comment: @OsamaAftab what is the value for `new TimerUtil().getAuctionInterval();` (←this also not a good practice

Comment: 1000 i.e 1 second

Comment: @OsamaAftab I am running currently 300 timers on my server, all within -+ 10ms precision. How many timers do you have now

Comment: Unlimited there is no limit for auctions

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using [this](https://www.hangfire.io/overview.html) framework.